# Link a list view to Site contents

Tags: list-view

I have created a list and then made views where I have selected to only see specific domains but now my supervisor would like to get the views to show up in site contents (separate from the list). Is there any way that this is possible? We are using SP 2013

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of site contents, you may add in "Site Actions" which can be done using feature.

Or may be in quick launch.

Answer (score 0):

Site Contents is only designed to show lists, libraries, apps, and sites and it isn't configurable.

One easy way to address exposing these list view pages is to use the built-in navigation (left and/or top) and create links to your list views.

Another option along the same lines would be to create a single "index" page that you link to in the navigation.  On this "index" page you either have links to the different views or web parts to the different views.